# Margin-right: auto not working in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to get my logo on the left side and some nav buttons on the right side, but the logo just refuses to budge.

```
 <div class="flex-container">
    <div><img onclick="location.href='index.html'" src="arvax_logo.png" class = "logo"/></div>
    <div><input type="button" onclick="location.href='about.html';" value="About" /></div>
    <div><input type="button" onclick="location.href='faq.html';" value="FAQ" /></div>
    <div><input type="button" onclick="location.href='resources.html';" value="Resources" /></div>
  </div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: unset;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo{
  height: 60.5px;
  width: 272px;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609#33856609) that this was the way to do it, but I keep getting:
[image]

Comment: try adding flex-grow: 1; in .logo css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you. Split the image and menu into their own groups and then use `justify-content: space-between` to put them on opposite sides.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <img onclick="location.href='index.html'" src="arvax_logo.png" class = "logo"/>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href='about.html';" value="About" />
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href='faq.html';" value="FAQ" /></div>
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href='resources.html';" value="Resources" />
    </div>
 </div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo{
  height: 60.5px;
  width: 272px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `logo` class to the parent div of the image, which is on the same level as the div elements which contain the input elements (i.e. all these being the flex items, as direct children of the flex container), not to the image itself. Or add another class to that div and set up a CSS rule for that one containing `margin-right: auto`